# Customize gitlab "Create Repository" instructions for new projects

Tags: git, repository, gitlab

I would like to customize Gitlab repository creation to include instructions for the clients to create a new repo, and then git clone a common set of patches.  Is there a template that I can edit within the Gitlab configuration to enable this to be added?

TIA

Comment: Actually, I think I found the file I need to edit. /opt/bitnami/apps/gitlab/htdocs/app/views/projects/empty.html.haml  Will report success back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that in addition of [`app/views/projects/empty.html.haml`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/app/views/projects/empty.html.haml), there is a request for that repo to be created on project creation ([issue 4167](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/4167) and [suggestion 3797854](http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general/suggestions/3797854-create-empty-repo-on-project-creation)).
This would be easier than having to init locally and push up.